# Best way to extend Unity3d Rigidbody?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

I am designing a physics class library for Unity3d and would love to be able to hook and inject functionality into Unity3d's `Rigidbody` class, but it's my understanding that there is no way to do this directly while still being able to target all platforms.

I thought the next best thing might be to create a new class that inherits directly from `Rigidbody`.  However, it looks like unity has prevented this from occurring in anything but  the UnityEngine namespace by requiring the `internal sealed ExtensionOfNativeClassAttribute` on anything that inherits native classes.  Furthermore, Unity does not searialize inherited classes well.

So, in review, I'm not able to hook into `Rigidbody` directly (Please correct me if this is wrong!), and I'm not able to inhert from `Rigidbody` directly (Please correct me if this is wrong!). I think the next best option is to:

1. Create a new Monobehavior, let's say it's called `ModRigidbody`, which makes a parellel implementation of all of `Rigidbody`'s members.  This class does not actually inherit from `Rigidbody`, but merely has members with all the same names / signatures as `Rigidbody`.
2. On `ModRigidbody` add the attribute `[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]`.  Now I can add functionality to some ModRigidbody's members as I see fit, and have other members simply 'pass through' to `transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`.
3. Have any end users (programmers) change all of their references to `Rigidbody` over to `ModRigidbody`.

To me this feels quite sloppy.  Is there a way to mod the functionality of `Rigidbody` so that future users of this library will not have to change all of their `Rigidbody` over to `ModRigidbody`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposition seems reasonable given the constraints imposed by Unity, but why not create an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)?

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type.

---

I'll start by saying that even extending `Rigidbody` directly will cause your consumers to migrate to using a new type in their implementations so creating a [proxy](https://www.dofactory.com/net/proxy-design-pattern) is certainly a good start. However, if you want to promote consumers using `Rigidbody` directly instead of a new type, then I recommend creating extension methods:

```cs
public static class ForceApplicationRigidbodyExtensions {
    public static void ApplyDecayingForce(
        this Rigidbody rigidbody,
        Vector3 startingForce,
        float decayRate,
        TimeSpan lifetime) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This allows consumers to invoke your methods directly off of their `Rigidbody` instances:

```cs
var rigidbody = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
rigidbody.ApplyDecayingForce(Vector3.up * 10, 0.05f, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

If you're not a fan of extension methods, then you *could* create something focused on mutating a given `Rigidbody` instead:

```cs
public class RigidbodyForceApplicator {
    private reaodnly Rigidbody _rigidbody;
    public RigidbodyForceApplicator(Rigidbody rigidbody) =>
        _rigidbody = rigidbody;
    public void ApplyDecayingForce(
        Rigidbody rigidbody,
        Vector3 startingForce,
        float decayRate,
        TimeSpan lifetime) {
        ...
    }

}
```

This allows consumers to be explicit while using only what they need:

```cs
var rigidbody = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
var forceApplicator = new RigidbodyForceApplicator(rigidbody);
forceApplicator.ApplyDecayingForce(Vector3.up * 10, 0.05f, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

If you *do* create a proxy instead, then I recommend keeping the following points in mind:

- Don't expect `Rigidbody` to fully support the mutations you have in mind as that almost never works out the way we intend.
- Don't create pass-through implementations that hand work off directly to `Rigidbody` as this just adds an extra method invocation that isn't necessary.
- Only expose functions that provide what you intend to complement `Rigidbody` with.

Comment: Thank you for the great response.  One requirement that I failed to mention in my first post is that I need to keep track of some additional state.  I think in my case, this precludes me from using extension methods alone.  I will update my original post to reflect this.

Comment: The applicator pattern and proxy pattern could very well work.  I will keep the question open for a while to see if anyone else replies with additional suggestions.  If not, I will accept this as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @marcAKAmarc, I'm curious to see a consumer-oriented use case with a focus on the state information you want to track. With that new knowledge, I might be able to adjust my answer to account for it.

Comment: My use case is a bit complicated.  A simplified version: I am interested in taking all forces applied to one rigidbody and re-applying those forces to another 'entangled' rigidbody.  The reference to the entangled rigidbody would be the added state.  This added state would not be exposed or managed by the consumer.

Comment: @marcAKAmarc, using the word "entangled" implies that it's one-to-one and that a force exerted on one should also be applied to the other. This can still be done with an extension method, unless, you need to capture forces applied over time and apply them to the entangled `Rigidbody` at a later time (so delayed reactions). If delayed reactions are the goal, then the proxy method is your best bet, and I'd still couple it with extensions that spit out the proxy model as an `out` parameter.